# Is that formula a sentence? (are there free variables?)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

\[\forall xP\]

P is a predicate symbol and 0-ary.

I'm studying first order logic and I have some doubts about free variables.
In this case, we have the occurrence of the variable x. Is that a free variable?

P is a predicate constant without terms (or 0-ary).

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. Quite frankly, this question looks emaciated. On this site, some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Best of luck to you.

Comment: The syntactical rules for FOL "usually" does not impose that, in order to use a quantifier, there is a free var in its scope. Thus, a formula $\forall x \varphi$ is correct also if $\varphi$ has no *free* occurrences of $x$. Thus, if $P$ is a $0$-ary predicate symbol, i.e. a propositional constant, it has no free vars; also $\forall x P$ has no free vars, and thus it is a *sentence*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is all right to have unused variables in a sentence, as long as they are each bound by a quantifier.

In a comment you worried that the $x$ in $\forall x P$ would cause problems as a ${\it free\ variable}$, but in fact it is not free. A free variable is one that appears without a quantifier to bind it, like $y$ in the formulas $P(y)$ and $\forall x P(x,y)$, which consequently are not sentences. (Or maybe in your notation these are written as $P_y^1$ and $\forall x P_{x,y}^2$.)